# layout with h:selectoneradio

Tags: css, jsf-2

how do you get h:selectOneRadio to not display items inline, considering it only renders one row? or how do you get it to render one row per item?

```
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{cc.attrs.radioItem}" styleClass="radioOptions">
                <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.radioItems}" />
                <f:ajax render="detailPanel :pricingTable" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: the items are rendered one next to the other. i want them one underneath the other. the style class is empty, i was trying out different things, to no avail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set the `layout` attribute to `pageDirection`.

```html
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{cc.attrs.radioItem}" layout="pageDirection">
```

This would not easily be fixable by CSS as it actually renders a `<table>`.

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.1 tag documentation index](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/)

  - [`<h:selectOneRadio>` tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectOneRadio.html)

Comment: oh. right. i was trying weird workarounds and the answer was right under my nose. thank you

Comment: Hi BalusC, is there a way to custom the layout of the selectOneRadio? Like instead of display 8 of them in a row, display 4 on each row?