# What does the layout property mean in JSF tags?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

Please can anyone explain what the layout property represents in this tag?

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="" layout="pageDirection" border="1">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="red" itemValue="1" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="white" itemValue="2" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [layout with h:selectoneradio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139493/layout-with-hselectoneradio).

Basically, JSF can lay out the radio buttons horizontally by `layout="lineDirection"` or vertically by `layout="pageDirection"`.

Here's the [`<h:selectOneRadio>`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_selectOneRadio.html) reference for you.

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes and buttons can be set up to either go next to each other on the current line (layout="lineDirection") or stacked vertically, with line breaks after each one (layout="pageDirection").

Since the component is writing a bunch of HTML on your behalf, this just affects how it does it.